# MemoryMappedFile and FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

Is it possible to combine MemoryMappedFile and a FileSystemWatcher? In other words, how to get the path of a mem mapped file for FileSystemWatcher's constructor:

```
new FileSystemWatcher(someMemMappedPath);
```

What string should "someMemMappedPath" contain?

Author's edit: I'm not creating the memorymapped file from a physical file, but from an object. I have multiple applications (processes) that I want to simulate "events" to communicate with each other - and I don't want to use named pipes. It seems that it's not possible to hook up FileSystemWatcher. I'm going for a thread-polling solution instead, where I just make a flag in the file if it's been changed by a process so another process can get notified when their thread reads the file.

Comment: Please somebody explain why somebody voted this question down? On what grounds? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Updated to answer the new question*

> I'm not creating the memorymapped file from a physical file, but from an object. I have multiple applications (processes) that I want to simulate "events" to communicate with each other - and I don't want to use named pipes

You should still be able to use Peters answer as there is a file on disk somewhere, but with a autogenerated file name.

However, if you want to be able to send events between systems that is a fragile solution. What happens when the file gets corrupted?

A better way is to introduce message queuing. If the applications are on the same machine this is pretty easy using MSMQ. Create one queue per application and send each notification to every queue. In this way you get an guarantee that no one of the listeners looses a message.

The article as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx) contains several examples

Comment: And if the OP already has a `MemoryMappedFile` object and doesn't know the filename, how does this answer his question?

Comment: @PeterRitchie: Where do he say that he didn't create it?

Comment: Why would they ask what filename to use with `FileSystemWatcher` if they created a `MemoryMappedFile` with a filename?

Comment: My point is that if they created the file they can switch to the static method which is used to specify a filename.

Comment: Then the answer to the question would be `someMemMappedPath = @"c:\ExtremelyLargeImage.data"`...

Comment: Don't you think he can understand that himself when the static method is pointed out? Have a little faith

Comment: Thank you but this answer doesn't incorporate filesystemwatcher. I did not downvote.

Comment: I know, it was Peter. But is it you who create the MemoryMappedFile?

Comment: read my comment on Peter's... you are right, MSMQ is better way.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the expectation with `MemoryMappedFile` objects is that you know the filename yourself.  i.e. there's nothing in the `MemoryMappedFile` object to get the filename that the memory is mapped to.

You'd have to use the `MemoryMappedFile.SafeMemoryMappedFileHandle` property and pinvoke [`GetMappedFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683195%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the original filename used to create the `MemoryMappedFile` object.

The output from `GetMappedFileName` would be what you pass to `FileSystemWatcher`.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but this doesn't work for me. I'll upvote.

Comment: To be clear, I create the file with a not-Path name, eg. "mytempdata", instead of "c:\temp\whatever"...so I actually don't know the location of the file, I'm thinking the file does not physically exist on the disk.